# how to trim request param values before validating them with spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I have code like this:

```kotlin
data class LoginParams(
        @field:NotNull
        @field:Email
        @field:Size(min = 1, max = 100)
        val email: String?,
        @field:NotNull
        @field:Size(min = 4, max = 100)
        val pass: String?
)

@PostMapping("/login")
fun login(@Valid params: LoginParams){
   //...
}
```

I want the `email` field to be `trim()`'ed before doing the `@Size` validation on it. how do I achieve so?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to perform trim with bean validation though instead of `@field:Size` you can use `Pattern` to allow spaces around the data as:

```
@field:Pattern(regexp="^\s*[\S]{1,100}\s*$")
```

- `^\s*`: start matching 0 or more spaces
- `[\S]{1,100}`: match 1-100 non-space characters
- `\s*$`: match 0 or more spaces at the end of the match

or Optionally, custom validator can be created to implement custom validation login with

```
// in your custom annotation interface file
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomTrimSizeValidator.class)
```